# Build realTime notification using angular 4,Node js mysql

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, server, socket.io

I need examples of real time notifications using Angular 4, Node js.
I am working on project about sharing articles between neighbors using Angular4 on frontend and symfony3 on backend, in my project i use notifications to inform neighbors  about witch articles they want to borrow by clicking on button "borrow"

Comment: Provide more details, are you using a restful api, have you attempted anything/read the socket.io docs?

Comment: I used the restful Api to connect the backend with frontend and I read the documentation of socket.io. unfortunately, i didn't found any example about notification to follow to connect between users.

Comment: Just follow the chat setup, and instead of a messaging area, catch the notifications within your angular setup, send them on restful api actions

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend adding [angular2-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster), it is an easy to use notification system that will run on the 'client side' (angular 4 side) that the user will see.
Then you will need to setup socket.io, https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ follow the chat tutorial but instead of chat, set it up with angular2-toaster for notifications.

Now in your RESTFUL API, when a call is made (in your NodeJS backend for instance, when a user adds 'action' that relates to another user, maybe a 'neighbor' as you say) stream to socket.io the relevant information to the neighbor.

In angular 4 have a listener for socket.io from your backend and subscribe angular2-toaster notifications to it!